# mvn test dando erro 'cannot find symbol'

Tags: spring-boot, maven, testes

Tenho um projeto spring-boot e estou programando alguns testes usando o Junit, no Eclipse eu executei os testes sem ter problemas, porem, no terminal, ao tentar executar o comando **mvn test** ou **mvn build** ocorre um erro na minha classe TestUtil que nunca aconteceu no Eclipse dizendo  'cannot find symbol'.

Sera que não esta encontrando a classe ?

O erro é esse:

```
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /home/andre/Documentos/workspace-sts/ecommercespringboot/src/main/java/br/eti/krebscode/ecommercespringboot/utils/TestUtil.java:[8,20] package org.hamcrest does not exist
[ERROR] /home/andre/Documentos/workspace-sts/ecommercespringboot/src/main/java/br/eti/krebscode/ecommercespringboot/utils/TestUtil.java:[9,20] package org.hamcrest does not exist
[ERROR] /home/andre/Documentos/workspace-sts/ecommercespringboot/src/main/java/br/eti/krebscode/ecommercespringboot/utils/TestUtil.java:[61,54] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class TypeSafeDiagnosingMatcher
  location: class br.eti.krebscode.ecommercespringboot.utils.TestUtil
[ERROR] /home/andre/Documentos/workspace-sts/ecommercespringboot/src/main/java/br/eti/krebscode/ecommercespringboot/utils/TestUtil.java:[70,54] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Description
  location: class br.eti.krebscode.ecommercespringboot.utils.TestUtil.ZonedDateTimeMatcher
[ERROR] /home/andre/Documentos/workspace-sts/ecommercespringboot/src/main/java/br/eti/krebscode/ecommercespringboot/utils/TestUtil.java:[86,32] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Description
  location: class br.eti.krebscode.ecommercespringboot.utils.TestUtil.ZonedDateTimeMatcher
[ERROR] /home/andre/Documentos/workspace-sts/ecommercespringboot/src/main/java/br/eti/krebscode/ecommercespringboot/utils/TestUtil.java:[69,9] method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
[ERROR] /home/andre/Documentos/workspace-sts/ecommercespringboot/src/main/java/br/eti/krebscode/ecommercespringboot/utils/TestUtil.java:[85,9] method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
[INFO] 7 errors 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.309 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-06-24T00:15:51-03:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 31M/285M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:compile (default-compile) on project ecommercespringboot: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /home/andre/Documentos/workspace-sts/ecommercespringboot/src/main/java/br/eti/krebscode/ecommercespringboot/utils/TestUtil.java:[8,20] package org.hamcrest does not exist
[ERROR] /home/andre/Documentos/workspace-sts/ecommercespringboot/src/main/java/br/eti/krebscode/ecommercespringboot/utils/TestUtil.java:[9,20] package org.hamcrest does not exist
[ERROR] /home/andre/Documentos/workspace-sts/ecommercespringboot/src/main/java/br/eti/krebscode/ecommercespringboot/utils/TestUtil.java:[61,54] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class TypeSafeDiagnosingMatcher
[ERROR] location: class br.eti.krebscode.ecommercespringboot.utils.TestUtil
[ERROR] /home/andre/Documentos/workspace-sts/ecommercespringboot/src/main/java/br/eti/krebscode/ecommercespringboot/utils/TestUtil.java:[70,54] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class Description
[ERROR] location: class br.eti.krebscode.ecommercespringboot.utils.TestUtil.ZonedDateTimeMatcher
[ERROR] /home/andre/Documentos/workspace-sts/ecommercespringboot/src/main/java/br/eti/krebscode/ecommercespringboot/utils/TestUtil.java:[86,32] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class Description
[ERROR] location: class br.eti.krebscode.ecommercespringboot.utils.TestUtil.ZonedDateTimeMatcher
[ERROR] /home/andre/Documentos/workspace-sts/ecommercespringboot/src/main/java/br/eti/krebscode/ecommercespringboot/utils/TestUtil.java:[69,9] method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
[ERROR] /home/andre/Documentos/workspace-sts/ecommercespringboot/src/main/java/br/eti/krebscode/ecommercespringboot/utils/TestUtil.java:[85,9] method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[
```

E o código da minha classe TestUtil é esse:

```
package br.ecommercespringboot.utils;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeParseException;

import org.hamcrest.Description;
import org.hamcrest.TypeSafeDiagnosingMatcher;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.JavaTimeModule;

public class TestUtil {

    /** MediaType para JSON UTF8 */
    public static final MediaType APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8 = new MediaType(
        MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON.getType(),
        MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON.getSubtype(), Charset.forName("utf8"));

    /**
     * Converte um objeto para JSON byte array.
     *
     * @param object
     *            o objeto para converter
     * @return JSON byte array
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public static byte[] convertObjectToJsonBytes(Object object)
        throws IOException {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);

    JavaTimeModule module = new JavaTimeModule();
    mapper.registerModule(module);

    return mapper.writeValueAsBytes(object);
    }

    /**
     * Crie uma matriz de bytes com um tamanho específico preenchido com dados especificos.
     * 
     *
     * @param size tamanho do byte array
     * @param data dados para colocar no byte array
     * @return o JSON byte array
     */
    public static byte[] createByteArray(int size, String data) {
    byte[] byteArray = new byte[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        byteArray[i] = Byte.parseByte(data, 2);
    }
    return byteArray;
    }

    /**
     * Um correspondente que testa que a cadeia examinada representa o mesmo instante que a data e hora de referência.
     */
    public static class ZonedDateTimeMatcher extends TypeSafeDiagnosingMatcher<String> {

    private final ZonedDateTime date;

    public ZonedDateTimeMatcher(ZonedDateTime date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean matchesSafely(String item, Description mismatchDescription) {
        try {
            if (!date.isEqual(ZonedDateTime.parse(item))) {
                mismatchDescription.appendText("was ").appendValue(item);
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        } catch (DateTimeParseException e) {
            mismatchDescription.appendText("was ").appendValue(item)
                .appendText(", which could not be parsed as a ZonedDateTime");
            return false;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void describeTo(Description description) {
        description.appendText("a String representing the same Instant as ").appendValue(date);
    }
    }

    /**
     * Cria um correspondente que corresponde quando a cadeia examinada representa a mesma instância que a data e hora de referência
     * @param date datetime de referência em relação ao qual a sequência examinada é verificada
     */
    public static ZonedDateTimeMatcher sameInstant(ZonedDateTime date) {
    return new ZonedDateTimeMatcher(date);
    }

}
```

Comment: Talvez valha a pena você adicionar o `pom.xml` também.

Answer (score 0):

Eu queria executar os testes e depois gerar o .jar do projeto, o erro que cometi foi que em vez de executar o comando mvn package eu executei o mvn build e por isso acontecia o erro, confundi os comandos.
Agora esta funcionando!